How to get the correct brew on mushroom coffee
I'm giving mushroom coffee a try. I picked up a jar from a local herb shop. There were no directions. Based on some research, I'm putting a little less than a tablespoon in a cup with boiling water. It does not taste like coffee to me. It has more of a tea/chai flavor.
I'm curious if there is an optimal temperature for water when brewing mushroom coffee. I use an electric kettle. When making a French Press, I heat the water to 205 Fahrenheit, but I heat it at a higher temp for black tea and lower temps for green and white teas. What is the best temperature for mushroom coffee?
